# Does vwo(visual website optimizer) slow down website load time in any manner?

Tags: optimization, web, vwo

Visual website optimizer is a A/B testing tool which can help one site owner to analyze his site with a modified of that. It puts a simple code in your website and make a new version of your web page.Then it show one version of your webpage to 50% of your visitors and another ver to rest of the 50%. This way the owner can analyze which ver of the site is generating more revenue & dump the other one.

So my question is can vwo reduce the site loading time somehow?Or what is the drawbacks of using vwo in a website?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a little bit of additional lag in load time, as the script that makes the decision has to call home to the VWO servers, see what variations should be served, then serve that particular page.

The trick to minimising that loading lag is to put the script absolutely first on the target page, so that nothing else is happening before the script fires (but you'll always have lag).

Answer (score 0):

This blog post by VWO sums everything up: https://vwo.com/blog/how-vwo-affects-site-speed/

They write in that post:

> Having said all this, we are confident that VWO’s best-in-class technology coupled with optimal campaign settings will ensure that your website never slows down

However, I would suggest to test it out on your page and see whether it works for you or not.